# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I keep on getting this error when using this code.
SRC --> http://jsfiddle.net/MYG2C/1/

JS

```
    <input class="menu1" type="submit" value="Total : 0.00" onclick="m.getTotal()" id="total" />
```

HTML

```
var m = {
    total:0,
    getTotal: function () {
        this.total = this.total.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementByID("total").value = "Total : " + this.total;
    },
}
m.total = 5;
//Clicking the button should now update the text on the button.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems...

- `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`
- `this.total = this.total.toFixed(2);` will work the first time because `total` is a number. After that it becomes a string and `toFixed` is not a valid method on a string

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8J2G7/)

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo as anthony chu mentioned and below is the modified script for check the type and avoid the Uncaught TypeError.

```
var m = {
    total:8,
    getTotal: function () {
        if(typeof this.total == "number")
        {
        console.log("executed");
        this.total = this.total.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("total").value = "Total : " + this.total;
        }
    },
}
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/8J2G7/4/